# Passing relative paths of scripts to powershell jobs

Tags: multithreading, powershell, powershell-3.0, jobs

I have functions in separate files I need to run as jobs in one main file.

I need to be able to pass these functions arguments.

Right now my problem is figuring out how to pass the path of the function files to the jobs in a way that is not completely awful.

I need to have the functions defined at the top of the file for readability (just having a static comment that says "script uses somefunc.ps1" is not adequate)

I also need to refer to the scripts relative path (they will all be in the same folder).

Right now I am using env: to store the path of the scripts, but doing this I need to refer to the script in like 5 places!

This is what I have:

testJobsMain.ps1:

```
#Store path of functions in env so jobs can find them
$env:func1 = "$PSScriptRoot\func1.ps1"
$env:func2 = "$PSScriptRoot\func2.ps1"

$arrOutput = @()
$Jobs = @()
foreach($i in ('aaa','bbb','ccc') ) {

    $Import = {. $env:func1}
    $Execute = {func1 -myArg $Using:i}

    $Jobs += Start-Job -InitializationScript $Import -ScriptBlock $Execute
}

$JobsOutput = $Jobs | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
$JobsOutput

$Jobs | Remove-Job
#Clean up env
Remove-Item env:\func1
$arrOutput
```

func1.ps1

```
function func1( $myArg ) { write-output $myArg }
```

func2.ps1

```
function func2( $blah ) { write-output $blah }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make array of paths, and then pass one of paths/all of them in `-ArgumentList` param from Start-Job:

```
#func1.ps1
function add($inp) {
    return $inp + 1
}

#func2.ps1
function add($inp) {
    return $inp + 2
}

$paths = "$PSScriptRoot\func1.ps1", "$PSScriptRoot\func2.ps1"

$i = 0
ForEach($singlePath in $paths) {
    $Execute = {
        Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)]
             [String]$path
        )
        Import-Module $path
        return add 1
    }
    Start-Job -Name "Job$i" -ScriptBlock $Execute -ArgumentList $singlePath
    $i++
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt 2; $i++) {
    Wait-Job "Job$i"
    [int]$result = Receive-Job "Job$i"
}
```

You can skip all those $i iterators with names, Powershell will name jobs automatically, and easly predictable: Job1, Job2.. So it would make code a lot prettier.